# CSS set width of element to 110% of previous child

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a  element whos width is dependent on its content. The next child is a

---

tag which I want to take up 110% width of the  tag but max-width of 100% of parent. All of this is wrapped in a div whos width is 100% page width. The desired outcome would look like this
[image: Desired outcome]

The current code I have is

```
<div class="heading">
        <h2>Locally Links</h2>
        <hr/>
    </div>

.heading {
    color: #2d3748;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    h2{
        width: max-content;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        font-size: 3rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    h3{
        font-size: 1.875rem;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
   
    hr {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 21rem; 
        height: 4px;
        background: linear-gradient(90deg,#4097e9,#51dab8);
    }
}
```

I have attempted to solve this via psuedoelements but I'm not sure if thats the correct approach. Currently I can get it to either be the width of the text or the width of the parent but not 110% of the width of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```css
.heading {
  color: #2d3748;
  display: table; /* fit text width */
  margin:auto; /* center */
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

hr {
  /* your 110% width */
  margin-left:-5%;
  margin-right:-5%;
  /**/
  height: 4px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #4097e9, #51dab8);
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <h2>Locally Links</h2>
  <hr/>
</div>

<div class="heading">
  <h2>Links</h2>
  <hr/>
</div>
```

That you can simplify with a pseudo element:

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #2d3748;
  display: table; /* fit text width */
  margin:50px auto; /* center */
}

h2::after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  /* your 110% width */
  margin-left:-5%;
  margin-right:-5%;
  /**/
  height: 4px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #4097e9, #51dab8);
}
```

```html
<h2>Locally Links</h2>

<h2>Links</h2>
```